# x:Shared MarkupExtension in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Is there a workaround for the missing x:Shared MarkupExtension in silverlight?

I have the following Xaml which is creating an ellipse on each target series. I need the ellipses to be unique as they are later added to canvas. By using this Xaml I get the error that the UIElement has already been added to another parent (e.g. single Ellipse instance added to Canvas multiple times).

In WPF I simply use the x:Shared property on this style to get it to work.

```
    <!-- Set the style for the series -->
    <Style TargetType="SciChart:FastLineRenderableSeries" >
        <Setter Property="SeriesColor" Value="#FF93F2C1"/>
        <Setter Property="ResamplingMode" Value="Mid"/>
        <Setter Property="RolloverMarker">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Ellipse Width="9" Height="9" Fill="#7793F2C1" Stroke="#FFA3FFC9"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

A workaround I considered was to create a control called RolloverMarker and set its control template. I'd appreciate any direct or indirect solutions to this problem.

Comment: `x:Shared` is not a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) but an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dynamically adding objects to a panel, then a new object needs to be created each time, or you need to define your control in some kind of Template and add a new data object which will use the Template. You cannot add the same item multiple times.

For example,

```
// Does not work
var templateItem = new FastLineRenderableSeries();
myCanvas.Add(templateItem);
myCanvas.Add(templateItem);


// Works
myCanvas.Add(new FastLineRenderableSeries());
myCanvas.Add(new FastLineRenderableSeries());
```

Or

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FastLineRenderableSeriesStyle}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
// Add items. They'll get rendered with defined ItemStyle.
var templateItem = new FastLineRenderableSeries();
SomeCollection.Add(templateItem);
SomeCollection.Add(templateItem);
```

Comment: Hello Rachel, In this case the FastLineRenderableSeries' are created (x3) in code, however they are styled in the Xaml. The part that fails is the Ellipse which is set in the style, this is set on a dependency property on FastLineRenderableSeries.RolloverMarker. Later this RolloverMarker is added to canvas in code. 

In WPF I have worked around this issue by using the x:Shared property on the style. However in Silverlight this is not possible. I want to create a new Ellipse for each intance of FastLineRenderableSeries that is styled. Can you think of any way? Regards,

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson The only way I can think to do that is to switch to using a `Template` instead of a hardcoded object. For example, if you had a `ContentControl` with it's `ContentTemplate` set to the `Ellipse`, then it should work because it will make a new `Ellipse` for every control instead of trying to re-use an existing one.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, that's what I had a hunch to try - glad you've confirmed it. I have attempted this in part and it seems to work. Going to continue down this road and see where it goes